# Statistical difference between two matrices

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have two matrices, for example;

x1 = [1,2,3];
y1 = [4,5,6];

m1 = [x1,y1];

x2 = [4,5,6];
y2 = [7,8,9];

m2 = [x2,y2];

How do I test if m1 and m2 are significantly different from one another?

Comment: More information and context is needed in order to answer this question. For example, if you talk about statistical difference between two matrices it's because there is some random process governing the generation of the values in each matrix. Also, each value in the matrix would have a sample size associated, i.e. the sample drawn from the said random process that is used to compute those values. So, please provide us with the (business?) context behind your question, with special attention to the two aforementioned aspects, and the goal you want to achieve that led you to ask this question.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't answer this question. Thank you for your help.